# TSQL Algebra - solve for x ((a)x < b)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, algebra

I have a table consiting of about 940 rows.  I am creating a specialised calculation that needs to solve the following:

For each row, how many times can I multiply A without it going above B.

I created a UDF to do this as follows:

```
DECLARE @x int;
DECLARE @Result decimal(18,4);
DECLARE @CutOff int;

SELECT @x=0, @CutOff=1000, @Result=null;

WHILE (((@Result < @tVal) or (@Result IS NULL)) AND @x < @CutOff) BEGIN 
    SET @x = @x + 1;
    SET @Result = @hProb * @x;
END

IF (@x = @CutOff)
    SET @x = -1;

RETURN @x;
```

- @tVal is the target value we are look to achieve.
- @CutOff is a maximum number to multiply by, if x reaches this number and still has not gone above the target value then stop the loop and return a negative number

This works but where my SP usually takes about 20 seconds to run, when I add this function it adds about 6.5 minutes to the processing time.

If possible I'd like a more efficient way to do this but I can't find a better solution so far.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I would guess there is a mathematical solution to this - using the log function.  Having a loop in UDF is what's causing your issue!

Comment: Why not just use something like `@Cutoff / @hProb`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is needing a codereview. try codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is `@tVal` in the statement `(@Result < @tVal)`? Is it supposed to be @CutOff? As Kieren said, the loop is 100% your problem, so if somebody has a creative way to solve it without looping you're golden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select case
    when @hProb * @Cutoff <= @tVal then -1
    else floor(@tVal / @hProb)
end;
```

And it might have side effects, depending on the actual data types of your arguments.

Comment: I think the cutoff value is meant to be `-1` rather than `@cutoff` (in the `then` clause) but otherwise, yes, this.

Comment: Thank you... I was simply over thinking the whole thing... the cutoff value was just a saftey valve to prevent the loop continuing for too long but the floor(tval / hprob) does exactly what I need... Much appreciated.